# Distance between two dates in Swift, when one is a string

Tags: ios, date, swift

I'm a bit of a newbie so be slow with me.

I'm making an app in swift, and I have a variable dateCreated, which is a string that has dates in the format of "yyyy-MM-dd."

I am trying to make another variable currentDate that is the current date, and find the number of days between them as an Int.

Can someone help me figure out the best way to do this? I have tried using methods from similar questions that I have found on this website, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far

Comment: To convert a string to NSDate user NSDateFormatter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is the NSCalendar framework which can help you calculate the difference between two dates. I suggest you create an extension to help you with it as follow:

```
extension Date {
    func days(from date: Date) -> Int {
        Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date, to: self).day!
    }
    func adding(days: Int) -> Date {
        Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: days, to: self)!
    }
    func adding(weeks: Int) -> Date {
        Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: weeks, to: self)!
    }
}
```

---

```
let yesterday = Date().adding(days: -1)   // "Mar 6, 2020 at 4:49 PM"
let lastWeek  = Date().adding(weeks: -1)  // "Feb 29, 2020 at 4:49 PM"

Date().days(from: yesterday)         // 1
Date().days(from: lastWeek)          // 7
```

---

If you need to calculate it from a String you can also create an extension to convert your string to Date as follow:

```
extension Formatter  {
    static let yyyyMMdd: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

---

```
extension String {
    var dateFromYearMonthDay: Date? { Formatter.yyyyMMdd.date(from: self) }
}
```

---

```
if let date = "2020-02-07".dateFromYearMonthDay {
    print(Date().days(from: date))  // "29\n"
}
```

Comment: `var numOfDays = NSDate().daysFrom(createDateNew.asDate)`

I tried using the code you posted, but on this line (taken from the last line of your second code block), I get an error that reads "NSDate does not have a member named 'daysFrom' "

Comment: How does that mean it's working?

Comment: If you get an error message that prevents the code from running, that means it's not working

Comment: Sorry about that, I accidentally left one of my lines as a comment. Everything is working now.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'd upvote your answer as well, but I just created my account today and you need at least 15 reputation.